# Polyline Rendering

Tags: c#, wpf, shapes

I have ItemsControl which is bound and creates multiple Polylines, one for each data item.

Currently I get "stack" like display - First Polyline at the top, below is second, below is third, and so on...

How can I make Polylines appear on the top of each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) of your `ItemsControl` (which is by default a `StackPanel` that's why you get the "stack" like display) to another `Panel` which allows it's Children to be placed on each other like the `Canvas` or the `Grid`:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```